# Find max/min in CUDA without passing it to the CPU

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia, cublas

I need to find the index of the maximum element in an array of floats. I am using the function "cublasIsamax", but this returns the index to the CPU, and this is slowing down the running time of the application.

Is there a way to compute this index efficiently and store it in the GPU?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the CUBLAS V2 API was introduced (with CUDA 4.0, IIRC), it is possible to have routines which return a scalar or index to store those directly into a variable in device memory, rather than into a host variable (which entails a device to host transfer and might leave the result in the wrong memory space).

To use this, you need to use the [`cublasSetPointerMode`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublassetpointermode) call to tell the CUBLAS context to expect pointers for scalar arguments to be *device* pointers by using the `CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE` mode. This then implies that in a call like

```
cublasStatus_t cublasIsamax(cublasHandle_t handle, int n,
                            const float *x, int incx, int *result)
```

that `result` must be a device pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CUBLAS and you have a GPU with compute capability 3.5 (K20, Titan) than you can use CUBLAS with dynamic parallelism. Than you can call CUBLAS from within a kernel on the GPU and no data will be returned to the CPU. 
If you have no device with cc 3.5 you will probably have to implement a find max function by yourself or look for an aditional library.